# how to correctly use kql operators ( =, >, >= ) in Grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, grafana, monitoring, dashboard

Right now I'm trying to transfer some old dashboards from kibana to Grafana 8.5+

Dashboards in kibana use filters for some mappings. For example we have some `event: "JOB_STARTED"` and this event comes with additional field `total_time: (time in milliseconds)`.

So in kibana we have the ability to sort by some time. For example `event: "JOB_STARTED" AND total_time >= 10000`. As a result we will get the number of such logs.

But in grafana as soon as I specify `AND total_time >= 10000`. The chart goes empty (or rather all of its values are zero). Whereas when you discovery the logs in kibana you see the exact number.

I couldn't find any solution. Maybe there is another way to filter or the operators ( =, >, >= ) are not normally supported in the grafana.

Comment: The `kql` tag is for Kusto Query Language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use [n TO N]. For example, in my case:

```
AND total_time: [10 TO 100]
```